# C# - How to list the files in a sub-directory fast, optimised way

Tags: c#, optimization, file-handling, directoryinfo

I am trying to list the files in all the sub-directories of a root directory with the below approach. But its taking much time when the number of files are in millions. Is there any better approach of doing this.

I am using .NET 3.5 so can't use enumerator :-(

```
        ******************* Main *************
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectoryInfo[] subDir = dir.GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in subDir) //call for each sub directory
        {
             PopulateList(di.FullName, false);
        }

        *******************************************
        static void PopulateList(string directory, bool IsRoot)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "dir /s/b \"" + directory + "\"");
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();

            string fileName = directory.Substring(directory.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName + ".lst");

            while (proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream != true)
            {
                 writer.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
                 writer.Flush();
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Why you can not use Enumerator within .NET 3.5? (you are saying `using .NET 3.5 so can't use enumerator`)

Comment: Directory.Enum... I thpought its not in 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all Process-related stuff and try out [Directory.GetDirectories ()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) methods:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllFiles(string rootDirectory)
{
    foreach(var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(
                                            rootDirectory, 
                                            "*", 
                                            SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
        {
            yield return file;
        }
    }
}
```

From MSDN, [SearchOption.AllDirectories:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx)

> Includes the current directory and all the subdirectories in a search
>   operation. This option includes reparse points like mounted drives and
>   symbolic links in the search.

Comment: This is not available in 3.5.

Comment: @Anton Gogolev : thanks, I've updated to GetDirectories() reference

Comment: I tried this method but I took error. Debug  bug,  doesnt stop in this method and also I saw this message: Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

It will be definitely faster to use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` in a loop for each directory instead of spawning tons of new processes to read thier output.

Answer (score 1):

With millions of files you're actually running into filesystem limitation (see [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28WS.10%29.aspx) and search for "300,000"), so take this into account.

As for optimizations, I think you'd really want to iterate lazily, so you'll have to P/Invoke into [`FindFirstFile`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FindFirstFile.html)/[`FindNextFile`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FindNextFile.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out already available [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) overload.
For example:

```
var paths = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And yes it will take a lot of time. But I don't think that you can increase its performance using only .Net classes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your millions of files are spread across multiple sub-directories and you're using .NET 4.0, you could look at the parallel extensions.

Using a parallel foreach loop to process the list of sub-directories, could make things a lot faster.

The new parallel extensions are also a lot safer and easier to use than attempting multi-threading at a lower-level.

The one thing to look out for is making sure that you limit the number of concurrent processes to something sensible.

Comment: sorry, didn't see the .net 3.5 requirement when I read it at first